# Possible example of stopped martingale not being in $L^1$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

I am looking at Lawler's stochastic process book, and for the optional stopping theorem, under the assumption for the stopping time that $\mathbb{P}(T<\infty) = 1$, he had

1. $\mathbb{E}[|M_T|]< \infty$, and
2. $\mathbb{E}[|M_n|{\bf 1}_{\{T>n\}}]$ goes to zero as $n\to \infty$.

I am confused by the first point, if we assume our martingale satisfies $M_n\in L^1$, could you help me with a simple example that
$$\mathbb{E}[|M_T|]= \infty?$$

Comment: As a complement to Jose Avilez's continuous-time answer, a discrete-time counterexample can be found in the book *Counterexamples in probability and statistics* (§6.17).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B_t$ be a Brownian motion and $Y$ a $(0,\infty)$-valued random variable such that $Y \not\in L^1$ and is independent from Brownian motion. Let $\mathcal{F}_t$ be the Brownian filtration augmented by $\sigma (Y)$. Define the stopping time $$T(\omega ) = \inf\{t\geq 0 \, : \,  |B_t|(\omega ) \geq Y(\omega) \}$$
Since $B_t$ a.s. takes on any value in finite time, we have that $P(T < \infty) = 1$. We also have: $$E(|B_T|) = E(Y) = \infty$$
Despite $B_t \in L^1$ for all $t$.

Comment: Very nice argument. Where do you use the fact that $B$ and $Y$ are independent though?

Comment: @charlus Thanks! It's to avoid technicalities, as not any $Y$ would do. I think if one were to pick $Y = |B_1|$, one may run into issues...

Comment: Isn't $|B_1|\sim |\mathcal{N}(0,1)|$, which does not have infinite expectation?

Comment: @charlus Sorry, say $Y = e^{B_1^5}$ which has infinite expectation. The point is that if you expand the Brownian filtration by $\sigma (Y)$, $B_t$ may no longer be a martingale in this case

Comment: You can avoid the expansion by modifying Jose's example slightly: $T:=\inf\{t>1: B_t=\exp(B_1^5)\}$.